# AmbiguousActionException in same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've been trying out Asp.NET Core, specifically Areas. Right now I'm running into an issue where I get an exception if I add more than one view to my controller.

This is my exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> Forum.Areas.Admin.Controllers.AdminController.Index (Forum)
> Forum.Areas.Admin.Controllers.AdminController.Testing (Forum)

This is how I register the route:

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute("adminRoute", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
```

My controller:

```
namespace Forum.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
  [Area("Admin")]
  [Route("admin")]
  public class AdminController : Controller
  {

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Testing()
    {
      return Content("Testing area!");
    }
  }
}
```

My project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Other similar questions seem to have ambiguous actions over different controllers, but in my case it's two different action names? Did I register the route wrong?

Edit: please no comments on my "2 spaces for tabs" indentation - it's a style guide from work, I have no say in it :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think in the Admincontroller you have Route("Admin") so .net is getting confused what you need is Route("Admin/[action]")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `Route` attribute in `AdminController`, because you registered routes in `app.UseMvc()` - delete `[Route("admin")]`.

Also, you should change your route in `app.UseMvc()`.

This route:

```
routes.MapRoute("adminRoute", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

should be changed to:

```
routes.MapRoute("adminRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You need to set area in route and default values for `controller` and `action`(it is not necessary to set defaults but it will be explained later in the answer).

So, to call `Index()` action you should type this `url`:

```
http://localhost:yourPortNumber/Admin
```

Here you make a request to `Admin` area and default values are used (`Admin` as default controller and `Index` as default action). You can change default values for this route.

**NOTE:** If you didn't set default values in your route then previous link would not work, you should write full `url` to action - see below.

To call `Testing()` action `url` should be:

```
http://localhost:yourPortNumber/Admin/Admin/Testing
```

Here you specify area name (`Admin`), controller name (`Admin`) and action name (`Testing`)

By the same way you can call `Index()` action and other actions (if you need more):

```
http://localhost:yourPortNumber/Admin/Admin/Index

http://localhost:yourPortNumber/Admin/Admin/AntoherActionName
```

So, your routes should be configured by this way:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute("adminRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

and your controller:

```
[Area("Admin")]  
public class AdminController : Controller
{     
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  public IActionResult Testing()
  {
    return Content("Testing area!");
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can also can set default area in routes configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute("adminRoute", "{area=Admin}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Now when you run your app by default will be used route:

```
http://localhost:your_port_number/Admin/Admin/Index
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem.

Comment: Using the same code above my index action is not called. It gives me "This localhost page can’t be found" error.

Comment: @SachinPakale, are you sure you set correct names for area, controller and action?

Comment: Yes, the following worked for me -         [Route("")]
        [Route("Admin")]
        [Route("Admin/Index")]
        public IActionResult Index()

Comment: @RomaDoskoch but your answer helped me understand the default behavior of app.UseMvc(). Thank you.

Comment: @SachinPakale, you don't need to set `[Route]` attribute at all (you can delete it) , because your routes are configured in `app.UseMvc()`. The answer for the question assumes that your area name is `Admin`, controller name is `AdminController` and action name is `Index`

Comment: @RomaDoskoch I have added new question if you can help me there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225917/mvc-6-areas-routing-is-not-redirecting-to-the-configured-page