# MVC 6 - Areas Routing is not redirecting to the configured page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2"

My project folder structure is as below

[image]

Code in startup.cs is below

[image]

When I run my project I am not redirected to the index page. It shows 404 Error.
Am I missing any setting?

Comment: I find this answer resolved, do you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535511/how-to-use-an-area-in-asp-net-core)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url should have this pattern (due to your routes configuration):

```
http://localhost:your_port_number/area_name
```

When you run your application your url pattern is:

```
http://localhost:your_port_number
```

There is no area name in the url.

You should specify the area `Admin` in url, because you don't have default area and you get `404 Not Found`, so your url should be like this:

```
http://localhost:your_port_number/Admin
```

**OR**

You can set default value for `Area` in `app.UseMvc()`:

```
routes.MapRoute("adminRoute", "{area=Admin}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Now by default you call endpoint in area `Admin` with controller name `Admin` and action name `Index`.

Comment: Setting Area name in app.UseMVC() worked for me. Now I my page is redirecting to Index.cshtml as expected. I also have removed [Area("Admin")] on my controller. I searched a lot about my issue but never got Area name in MapRoute. Now I wonder how does it work for others without specifying Area name in MapRoute.

Comment: Yes :) Thank you so much!